# Как закрепить несколько масок на одном фиксированном фоне?

Tags: html, css, svg

Я пытаюсь создать фрагмент, в котором у меня есть несколько элементов, за которыми расположен один общий фон. Оба круга имеют разную прозрачность. Они могут перемещаться, чтобы показать различные части фона. Я застрял, и у меня заканчиваются идеи. Как к этому подойти?

Моя попытка, чтобы результат выглядел так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to clip multiple masks to one single fixed background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68305784/7394871) от участника  [@Ashutosh Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14362086/ashutosh-gupta).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68305784/7394871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и с помощью **canvas**:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WicJ.jpg';

image.onload = () => { draw();};

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {draw()});

function draw(){

    let iW = image.width;
    let iH = image.height;
    
    let wW = canvas.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    let wH = canvas.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    
    let k = Math.min(wW/iW, wH/iH);
    
    let w = canvas.width = iW*k;
    let h = canvas.height = iH*k;
    
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.save();

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(w/2.7, h/2.7, Math.min(w,h)/3.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(w*2/3, h*2/3.5, Math.min(w,h)/4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
    
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,iW,iH,0,0,w,h);
    
    ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body {
    min-height: 98vh;

}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;   
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: black"></canvas>
```

Размер холста в пропорциях загруженного изображения. При изменении размера окна просмотра перестраивается.

---

Тема [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) обширна, добавил несколько рабочих вариантов. Последний "color" оставил все фигуры без изменения. Методов компоновки много, некоторые требуют обратный порядок, подложенный фон или объединение фигур для адекватного отображения эффекта.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w = canvas.width = 600;
let h = canvas.height = 180;

let image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WicJ.jpg';
image.onload = () => {draw()};

function draw(gco='source-in'){

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.save();

        
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(280, 80, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(350, 90, 70, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = gco;

    ctx.drawImage(image,0,(image.height - image.height*(h/w))/2,image.width,image.height*(h/w),0,0,w,h);
    ctx.restore();

}

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', e => {
        draw(e.target.value);
})
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: black"></canvas>

<select style="position: fixed; top:0; left: 0;">
    <option selected>source-in</option>
    <option>source-out</option>
    <option>destination-in</option>
    <option>xor</option>
    <option>lighter</option>
    <option>difference</option>
    <option>luminosity</option>
    <option>color</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Хорошо получилось, а адаптивно получится сделать в canvas, как в SVG?

Comment: Вот, как-то так)) Все вручную практически. Правда есть подвох: беру размеры родителя, а высота родителя по содержимому, то есть по размеру холста, которого еще нет, или минимальный 300*200 по умолчанию. Тут надо додумать. В данном случае родитель body, а я установил его минимальную высоту.

Comment: оч. интересно получилось, познавательно. Мне особенно понравилась фишка с `select`  c выбором types. В svg фильтрах есть аналогичные штуки, с теми же значениями, только они там называются операторами: xor,atop, screen, multiply и т.д. А так как canvas  намного моложе SVG, то наверно есть в этой теме что-то новое, надо сравнивать. Хотя судя по CSS фильтрам это очень урезанная копия SVG фильтров. Будем надеяться, что CSS вырастет ещё

Comment: Для растра в Canvas все есть, но не обязательно в виде готовых опций. Ведь есть доступ к BitMap, там уже можно манипулировать как угодно. Потерял сайт, где с помощью самодельных растровых фильтров-эффектов воспроизводили интересные вещи вроде эффекта линзы, волнообразных искажений, капель и т.д. И анимации в Canvas могут быть любыми, но "самодельными" и оттого часто не оптимизированными. А в SVG - автоматическая масштабируемость, встраиваемость в DOM, манипулирование как с обычными элементами, считывание пользовательских событий, подключаемость стилей, оптимизированная анимация и т.д.

Comment: `А в SVG - автоматическая масштабируемость` уточню,- если добавлен `viewBox` и размеры холста указаны в относительных единицах

Answer (score 3):

маска - это то, что вам нужно:

```css
.box {
  position:fixed;
  inset:0;
  -webkit-mask:
    /*                 control the opacity --v              position / size */
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 96%,#0000) 20% 50% / 300px 300px,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 96%,#0000) 70% 50% / 200px 200px,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
  mask-composite: exclude;
  background:#000;
}


html {
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1069/800/800) top/cover
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68307653/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

### Решение SVG mask

В качестве маски используются две окружности.
Разная прозрачность кругов обеспечивается разными цветами заполнения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:75vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 800 664" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<defs>
  <mask id="msk" > 
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" /> 
     <circle fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)" cx="280" cy="300" r="150" />
      <circle fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)" cx="420" cy="300" r="120" />
  </mask>
</defs>    
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
<image mask="url(#msk)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WicJ.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>   
</div>
```

Чтобы сделать фон немного видимым, добавим в маску

`<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#A96667" />`

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:75vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 800 664" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<defs>
  <mask id="msk" > 
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#A96667" /> 
    <circle fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)" cx="280" cy="300" r="150" />
      <circle fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)" cx="420" cy="300" r="120" />
  </mask>
</defs>    
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
<image mask="url(#msk)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WicJ.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>   
</div>
```

### Update

Все благодарности **[@Leonid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/342397/leonid)** за ценное  добавление в улучшении кода `fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"` которое позволило улучшить конечный результат (зона на пересечении масок стала выделена более светлым цветом)